# PhpMailer gmail error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas intento configurar el php con phpmailer y gmail pero no consigo que mande el mail.

```
$email_user = "email@gmail.com";
$email_password = "pass";
$the_subject = "Consulta tapa inodoro | Nashi";
$address_to = "detino@mail.es";
$from_name = "$nombre";
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
// ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail -------------------------------
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;

$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($email,$from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject;
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();

if(!$phpmailer->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

Me devuelve muchas cosas.

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp 
The following From address failed: fwefw@fefw.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp

SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp 
The following From address failed: fwefw@fefw.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: fwefw@fefw.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp

SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y8sm8438393wmi.8 - gsmtp
```

Comment: El problema no está en el puerto? Intenta con $mail->Port = 587;

Comment: lo probe y me devuelve esto `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)`

Comment: probá con $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; o también removiendo la línea $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP

Comment: si quito esa linea me sale esto `Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.`

Comment: Chequea este tutorial https://evilnapsis.com/2017/02/24/enviar-emails-con-la-libreria-phpmailer-y-configurar-gmail/ 


y tratá de seguir bien los pasos para configurarlo o verificá que esté todo configurado

Comment: Lo revise todo antes de preguntar además con es mismo tutorial :S. De  hecho solo me funciona con un servidor de dinahosting, otro que tengo de 1&1 o bien el gmail no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

Este código de arriba ha sido probado y trabajado para mí.

Puede ser que necesites `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

También asegúrese de que no haya activado la verificación de dos pasos para esa cuenta, ya que eso también puede causar problemas.

Vale la pena señalar que algunos servidores SMTP bloquean las conexiones. Algunos servidores SMTP no admiten SSL(o TLS) conexiones.

Comment: Vale localice el problema, esta en esta linea: `$phpmailer->setFrom($email,$from_name);` tiene que estar de este modo : `$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$email);` Lo que pasa que de este modo no puedo reponder al mail de la persona que lo recibo

Comment: Como puedo hacer para poder responder al mail que poner el cliente, si lo añado me sale tanto como desde el que lo recibo como el que pongo @leo_vilchis

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo la libreria PHPMailer y me funciona la siguiente configuración

```
$mail               = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = "ssl";
$mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port         = 465;
$mail->Username     = 'correo';
$mail->Password     = 'password';
$mail->From         = 'Envía';
$mail->FromName     = 'Nombre de quien envía';
$mail->Subject      = 'Asunto';
$mail->AltBody      = 'Asunto';
$mail->MsgHTML('Mensaje');
$mail->AddAddress('Correo_destino');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
if(!$mail->Send()){

    return $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $mail->ClearAddresses ();

    return "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
}
```

Otra cosa, tambien verifica la configuración de tu correo electrónico que pueda ser accedida desde otros dispositivos.

Comment: Dices "verifica la configuración de tu correo electrónico". ¿Cómo se configura eso? No lo encuentro por ningún sitio estre las opciones de gmail.